# How to do so that my field must at least be able to contain only numbers and a + in front of the number (if the user wishes)

Tags: reactjs, validation, formsy-react

For example the user can enter: +444123454656656 OR 123454656656 - only numbers or a + in front of the number.

```
<TextFieldFormsy
    className="myclasse"
    variant="outlined"
    label={t("phone_number")}
    id="phone_number"
    name="phone_number"
    value={phone_number}
    onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

Comment: How do you want to enforce this? With an error message or with an override?

Comment: filter on the entry and only take into account the numbers and the + character in front of it (if the user enters it)

Comment: You can simply filter the input in the onChange and save the input filtered.

Comment: I don't really know how to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can simply filter the input in onChange to remove everyting you do not want:

```
const isValidChar = (char, index) => {
    if(index === 0 && char === "+") {
        return true;
    } 
    return !isNaN(char);
}

const filteredInput = input.split("").filter((char, index) => isValidChar(char, index)).join("")
```

here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9nj6zqy7/) for the filter.

Comment: how can I integrate this into my <<TextFieldFormsy> thank you for the answer

Comment: Put this into the onChange method and save the filtered Input

Comment: Great, can you accept this answer, so others can find the solution too